# В чем ошибка?

Tags: jquery, javascript

В чем ошибка?

```
  $(".linkers").css("background-image", "url(fon.jpg) 100% 100% no-repeat")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".linkers").css("background", "url(fon.jpg) 100% 100% no-repeat")
```